# Permitir visualizar archivos sin permitir descarga directa

Tags: php, .htaccess, permisos

tengo una duda... la verdad no se si sea posible. En una web que estoy haciendo para un cliente estoy utilizando  (https://modelviewer.dev/) para renderizar un archivo .glb (son modelados 3d). La cuestión es que el cliente no quiere que su archivo de modelado se pueda descargar, al inspeccionar el código se ve la ruta del archivo y poniéndola directamente en el navegador se descarga. Ustedes saben alguna manera para bloquear solo la descarga pero que el recurso de  si la pueda leer?
PD. intenté bloquear las extensiones .glb desde el .htaccess pero no me renderiza el modelo porque el servidor lanza un 403.

```
<model-viewer src="https://mejorada.kratoxx.com/example.glb" ar="" ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" camera-controls="" poster="poster.webp" shadow-intensity="0" exposure="2" shadow-softness="1" ar-status="not-presenting">
```

Comment: Puedes colocar esos archivos fuera del directorio público, y servirlos desde PHP usando [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php), poniendo por ejemplo en el `header` un `Content-disposition: inline`.